# Unable to run unsupported-workflow: Error 1193: Unknown system variable 'transaction_isolation'

Tags: cadence-workflow

When running the  *unsupported-workflow* command on Cadence 16.1 against 5.7 Mysql Aurora 2.07.2 . I'm encountering the following error:

```
Error: connect to SQL failed
Error Details: Error 1193: Unknown system variable 'transaction_isolation'
```

I've set `$MYSQL_TX_ISOLATION_COMPAT=true` . Are there other settings I need to modify in order for this to run?

Comment: What is the version of your MySQL? I have added an answer but I think we should improve it.

Comment: 5.7 Mysql Aurora 2.07.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just fixed in https://github.com/uber/cadence/pull/4226 but not in release yet.

You can use it either building the tool, or use the docker image:

1. update docker image via `docker pull ubercadence/cli:master`
2. run the command `docker run --rm ubercadence/cli:master --address <> adm db unsupported-workflow --conn_attrs tx_isolation=READ-COMMITTED  --db_type mysql    --db_address ...`

For SQL tool:

```
cadence-sql-tool --connect-attributes tx_isolation=READ-COMMITTED ...
```

Comment: I'm running a CLI command:
`cadence admin db unsupported-workflow --db_type=mysql ....`
Not the db migration itself. This there a way to set this flag for the CLI?

Comment: Yeah I just realized that I misread it. Sorry, I will work on a fix tomorrow.

Comment: What is your MySQL version? I will fix and verify it.

Comment: We're running 5.7 Mysql Aurora 2.07.2 . Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: It's just fixed in https://github.com/uber/cadence/pull/4226 but not in release yet. You can use it either building the tool, or use the docker image: 1) update docker image via `docker pull ubercadence/cli:master` 2) run the command `docker run --rm ubercadence/cli:master adm db unsupported-workflow --conn_attrs tx_isolation=READ-COMMITTED  --db_type mysql    --db_address ...`

Comment: Awesome, I'll give this a shot. Thanks for all hard work.